# SQL copy row to another row in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, copy

I need to copy all values from row1 to row2 where now all records contains "no tiltle"

I already tried:

```
UPDATE `table` SET name=@tmp:=name,name=meta_title,meta_title=@tmp WHERE name='No Title';
UPDATE `bb_product_description` SET name = meta_title WHERE meta_title="No  Title"
```

but is just copy "No title to all"

Please help me

Comment: You don't use `"` in MySQL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm guessing you meant MSSQL, because MySQL can use them just fine (as long as ANSI_QUOTES sql mode is not enabled, which it is not in many cases).

Comment: @Uueerdo I am a MySQL user, haven't used it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @PraveenKumar given it is the ansi standard, it is probably best to not use them for strings; just stating that they are acceptable in common MySQL configurations.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a standard INSERT ... SELECT for this like so:

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM table WHERE meta_title='No Title';
```

Or be more selective (no pun intended)...

```
INSERT INTO table (name, col2, col3...) SELECT meta_title, col2, col3... FROM table WHERE meta_title = 'No Title'
```

Which, if I'm understanding your question correctly, should get you where you want to go.

Or, you could fix your UPDATE statement from above:

```
UPDATE `bb_product_description` SET `name` = `meta_title` WHERE `meta_title` = 'No Title'
```

Note I removed the extra space in 'No  Title' and changed from double- to single-quote because safety.

Comment: I dont get it work, maybe i didn't explained proper.

I have table X with column A and B, I want to take info from B and copy to A

Thank you for your answers and help

Comment: Try the UPDATE statement I put in above.  See if that works.